# Is vilification the process leading to vindication?

Tags: antonyms

Vindication is at the same time both an intoxicating and an unhealthy emotion.  It says, "I told you so."  "I was right despite your best efforts to dissuade or punish me."

An example of usage:

> Having previously observed that the English Language and Usage forum
>   abhors these sorts of questions, she was vindicated that, despite her
>   most creative efforts, her question was closed as unconstructive.

Given their pleasant `consonance` it seems to me that vilification (the creation of a villain) should be an appropriate contrasting term; the process immediately prior to vindication that makes it possible to be vindicated.  For example:

> For daring to test the authorities in this matter, she was vilified, and
>   her question unceremoniously closed.  Shall she be vindicated?

Have I correctly identified these words as contrasting terms or antonyms?  Does one immediately follow the other?

Comment: "Vindication" isn't an emotion and it isn't inherently unhealthy. The most common usage is to show that someone was *justified* or *blameless* in their actions or beliefs and is considered to hold a very positive connotation. I don't think your question makes a whole lot of sense; your examples of "vindicated" make me think you don't really understand what the word means or how it is used.

Answer (score 1):

[Vindication](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vindication) (“the act of vindicating or the state of being vindicated; evidence, facts, statements or arguments that justify a claim or belief”) is not a necessary consequence of  [vilification](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vilification) (“slanderous or malicious defamation; character assassination”), nor is vilification a necessary precursor of vindication.  Here are examples illustrating both cases:

> Judas has been vilified and his actions can never be vindicated.
>   Sam's idea was initially pooh-poohed but later was vindicated.

Note, *[to pooh-pooh](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pooh-pooh)* means “To dismiss idly, with derision or contempt”, which is a far cry from the usual sense of *[to vilify](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vilify)*, “To say defamatory things about someone or something”, although perhaps approaches a less common sense,  “To belittle through speech; to put down”.  The following form avoids even that objection:

> Sam's idea initially was thought wrong but later was vindicated.

Note, *[vindicated](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vindicated)* means  “justified, avenged or cleared of blame”.

Comment: I'd suggest 'praise' as a more reasonable candidate for an antonym of 'vilification'.

Comment: I think of verb *praise* as not quite effusive enough to be an antonym of *vilify* and instead suggest *glorify* or *exalt*.  (Similar comment for noun forms might apply)